# Java - Receiving a missing return error

Tags: java

I started taking a Java class last week and one of my assignments is to create a program that will take the GCD of two numbers, using what we have learned in class so far (so my program is probably not the most efficient). This is my program.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer");
        int num1 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter an integer");
        int num2 = console.nextInt();
        int gcd = factor(num1, num2);
        System.out.println("The GCD is " + gcd);
    }

    public static int factor(int num1, int num2) {
        int big = Math.max(num1, num2);
        int small = Math.min(num1, num2);
        int bigabs = Math.max(Math.abs(num1), Math.abs(num2));
        int smallabs = Math.min(Math.abs(num1), Math.abs(num2));

        if (smallabs == 0) {
            return bigabs;
        }
        if ((bigabs == 1) || (smallabs == 1)) {
            return 1;
        }
        for (int i = smallabs ; i >= 1; i--) {
            if ((num1 % i == 0) && (num2 % i == 0)) {
                return i;
            } 
        }
        // This is where I need a return statement
    }
}
```

It can't compile because it's missing a return statement. I believe that is because a method which requires a return type must declare a return statement for every possible branch in the method (correct me if I'm wrong). I know that in any scenario the numbers will go through the for loop's if statement, but the method doesn't know that. So my question is what return statement should I put? Does it really matter? Can someone explain this to me in detail because I have not learned much yet.

Comment: Add `return 1`, no other common denominator exists.

Comment: If you're sure that there isn't any way to get to that point in the code, throw an exception from there. If that exception doesn't get triggered, everything's good; if it does, it means that the method didn't work as you expected, and you'll want a nice, loud complaint to tell you that.

Comment: @yshavit How do you throw an exception? Sorry I don't really know much about java yet.

Comment: Not knowing about Java is fine; but not knowing about search engines is a bit more problematic. :) I was able to find Oracle's page about [how to throw exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) by googling literally your question ("how do you throw an exception?"). I didn't even need to add "java," though that's usually helpful for searching Java questions.

Comment: @yshavit Haha I like your sense of humor. :) I thought I could possibly get a direct answer from you. I did google it up but I found the explanation to be rather lengthy and hard for me to understand. I don't know half of the concepts mentioned on the page.

Comment: @Srm Then it's time to learn. :-) That is why your coding Java in the first place, right? To learn it.

Comment: try returning null from , where you posted to return something, compile and  then show stacktrace

Comment: I would suggest you stop the loop at `i = 2`. Currently, you *know* the loop will never end, because eventually it'll get to `i = 1`, and anything `% 1` is 0. Change the loop condition to `i > 1`, and follow advice of @ElliottFrisch: Add `return 1` at the end. That will eliminate the need to check `% 1 == 0`. You can then eliminate the `if ((bigabs == 1) || (smallabs == 1))` statement too, as being redundant.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I know. I guess I thought I could learn everything I need to learn in class (plus I am a bit lazy). But I think it's a good idea to do some out-of-school learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "lesson to learn" here isn't directly if you should return 1; or further rework your loop.

The key element here is what you wrote: *I know that in any scenario the numbers will go through the for loop's if statement, but the method doesn't know that.*

But the point is: your program is the expression of an algorithm. Each and any statement in that program must make "absolute" sense. Yes, sometimes programming languages are restricted; and you have to write something down just to make the compiler happy. But that is typically a bad sign. It means that you should probably spend some more time thinking about your code. In other words: any program should read "as natural" as possible. You only do things in your programs that make sense.

So, if you understand that your method **must** return from the loop statement at some point, and will **never** reach the end of the method, then a solution like

```
public int whatever() {
  ... for ( ... {
    return x;
  }

  throw new RuntimeException("will never be reached");
```

}

tells "everybody" what is going on: the compiler has a way to deal with the missing return; and human readers also understand the purpose of this construct easily.